# Soemtimes Google Recaptcha doesn't show images (but we will only get tick mark automatically)

Tags: php, html, contact-form, recaptcha

Google Recaptcha works fine, but sometimes it wont show images. It automatically gets a tick mark without verifying. It won't send the form details. Can anyone helps me? 
Acess the below link to check.

[Access my Website link](http://www.paint.netau.net/Contact-us.html)

It doesn't work mostly on mobile phone.

And I used the Recaptcha php library from Github 
[Github Recaptcha](https://github.com/google/recaptcha)

I have used the following code

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="ajax-contact-form1" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
   <?php 
  require_once "recaptchalib.php";
  // your secret key
$secret = "xxxxxx";
 
// empty response
$response = null;

// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// if submitted check response
 
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}
if ($response != null && $response->success) {
     
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
 
    $email_to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    $email_to2 = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    $email_to3 = "xxxx@outlook.com"; 
    $email_subject = "Play Of Paints Response";
 
    $success = false; 
 
  
  
    $first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
 
    
 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
 
    $telephone = $_POST['phone']; // not required
 
    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required
 
     
 
    $error_message = "";
 

 
    $email_message = "Devour...\n\n";
 
     
 
    function clean_string($string) {
 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
 
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
 
     
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
 
          
 
// create email headers
 
$headers = 'From: Play Of Paints<www.playofpaints.com>'.$email_to3."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email_to3."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
  @mail($email_to2, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
  $success = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    echo nl2br("Hello " . $_POST["name"] . " (" . $_POST["email"] . "), thanks for submitting the form! \n\n<strong>You will be contacted shortly!</strong>");
    
  } else { echo "Please enter your details below";

}
?>

  <div class="control-group">
<br>
      <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Your full name:</label>
      <div class="controls">          
       <input class="" type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" placeholder="Your full name:"  >
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Your email:</label>
      <div class="controls">          
        <input class="" type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Your email:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your email:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Your email:' ) this.value=''" >
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPhone">Phone number:</label>
      <div class="controls">          
        <input class="contact_phone" type="tel" id="inputPhone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Phone number:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Phone number:' ) this.value=''" >
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPhone">City</label>
      <div class="controls">          
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Bangalore" readonly>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputMessage">Message:</label>
      <div class="controls">                    
        <textarea class="" id="contact_message" name="message" placeholder="Message:" ></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfaGhETAAAAAMtEMP_dYoU-AbgaHLedpMWGiQ-7"></div>
     <br>
    
  <button type="submit" class="submit">submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: It works for me. Submits without error and it loos like you are using their new checkbox recapture instead of the image based one. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Yeah it works, but sometimes this problem occurs

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/recaptcha/?hl=en

go to section Using reCAPTCHA V2

> #### How do I use reCAPTCHA?
>
> Sometimes we need some extra info from you to make sure you’re human and not a robot, so we ask you to solve a challenge

only *sometimes* not *always*